# Hiding jobs that were not directly posted here

Tags: support, stack-overflow-jobs

I've a simple search query for open jobs that goes by a specific technology (C#) and then sorts by posting-date.

This works great for the most part but occasionally it looks like Stack Overflow picks up jobs from Indeed/LinkedIn etc and then this is just a mess, both in terms of suddenly finding 100+ jobs that were imported in the last few hours and also that these imported jobs are missing most of the nice-to-have fields.

I would like to only see jobs that were directly posted on Stack Overflow - is that possible?

For clarity here are the fields that are lacking:

- Company bio
- Job perks
- More jobs there,
- Finally, the ability to exclude them from my search (like you could do in Job preferences for directly posting companies)

Comment: Which fields in particular are you interested in?

Comment: Just off the top of my head - Company bio, job perks, link to more jobs there etc.
These imported jobs feel like clutter, for the lack of a better word, and the posted jobs feel like a curated experience, in comparison.

Comment: So, I'm guessing that this is not possible?!

Answer (score 3):

We put a lot of effort into keep Stack Overflow a high quality place for job listings. That includes negotiating with partners to ensure they comply with our quality criteria, and not importing jobs that don't pass those. This process is mostly automatic (though not exclusively), and we're constantly working on improving it.

That being said, jobs posted by hiring companies directly on our platform tend to be of the best quality.

Unfortunately there's currently no way to filter the job board to only include those. We might revisit if there's enough demand.

Comment: That is unfortunate, but I can see that it makes sense in your world.

Then there is a feature that is missing, I think. I had excluded "Crossover" as a company back when they were posting jobs directly on SO, but with these imported jobs, I do not see a way to exclude specific companies.

Fun fact: Crossover is still posting jobs and they are back in my feed, but now they are called "Crossover for Work" and are posting developer jobs for $30K!!!!

Look here 
https://stackoverflow.com/jobs/224296/c-sharp-net-software-engineer-30k-year-remote-crossover-for-work?so=p&pg=1&offset=15&q=c%23